# Initializing git flow in existing repository

Tags: git, github

I already have an existing repository with a couple of branches. Right now I have to initialize git flow here, using the source tree. But when I click on "git flow" button, and it tries to initialize the git flow, I get the following error:

```
sh.exe C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\gitflow_local\gitflow\git-flow init -d
fatal: Working tree contains unstaged changes. Aborting.

Completed with errors, see above.
```

I used git pull and git push on every branch, no uncommited changes...What's wrong?

Also, won't using git flow command on existing repo delete any files?

Answer (score 13):

You have *unstaged* changes. Which are changes on files that are tracked by git, but not commited or *added*, thus they are not *staged*. If you don't care about these changes you can use:

```
git reset --hard
```

To get back to you HEAD's state.

If you do care about these changes, you should add/commit them before you run your command. (You can see these changes with `git diff`).

Comment: Won't git reset --hard remove my latest commit, or any other files I have on master branch right now?

Comment: No, `git reset --hard` won't remove your latest commit, and it also won't touch files that are not tracked by git. It only removes *uncommitted* changes to *tracked* files. Alternatively you can use `git checkout` on the files that have *unstaged* changes to get them back to their state on you last commit.

Comment: But you loose your changes that way.

Comment: Those unstaged "changes" can be changes to file permissions. They don't show up when I compare a snapshot with local files, but git status reports them. Just happened to me.

Comment: I shoosed the second option (save changes) that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

AS I think you need to commit your changes.

`git commit -m "my commit message` You should code this.

If you don't want to keep your changes. You need to follow the instructions in the git status message and

use  `git reset HEAD <file>...`

Comment: What if I don't want to do either? Keep the changes for now but not committing them right now? When you plan to commit them say tomorrow.

Comment: Then use git stash to temporarily stash changes.

Answer (score 3):

Run git flow init from the repository folder just like as you would do for new repository

[Source: FAQ · nvie/gitflow Wiki](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/FAQ)